# Login to site with JS in a WebView and pass connection to JSoup

Tags: javascript, android, webview, jsoup

I'm trying to make an Android app for a site without app support and to login to the site you are required to submit your info through a form and submit via javascript.

I've successfully managed to sign in using evaluateJavaScript but am now just wondering how to properly pass on session data or cookies to a JSoup connection so that I stay logged in?

I would use just JSoup but the site only allows a connection to their login page from their server, can't post data from a direct connection to it.

I've tried mess around with CookieManager with no luck and CookieSyncManager even though it's deprecated.

Can anyone help?

Comment: depends, how does the site implements the authentication mechanism. Is it oauth? Is it basic http authentication? or is session passed with the url parameters? etc.

Comment: Is there I could find for sure? Right not it's just a simple ajax call submitting the info from the form to a page that throws a 403 error if accessed from anywhere but their domain so I can't post data to it directly. I thought maybe they were passing a session id as a cookie but my WebView doesn't have that cookie, only my full Chrome browser seems to get it.